# What do you call that foot/leg movement when you put on flip flops/sandals?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm thinking of the word to describe the movement of your foot and leg when you put on your flip-flops.

Is it correct to use ***slide***?

Feel free to change the sentence structure.

> I _____ my foot into my flip-flops.
>
> I ____ my foot out of my flip-flops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, slide is the correct verb.

> I slid my foot into my flip-flops
>
> I slid my foot out of my flip-flops

Comment: The verb slip would also work.